# Scrapy VS wget VS curl

Tags: curl, scrapy, web-crawler, wget

Im currently working on a project that requires 2 main functions:

1. Download only a single HTML page from a website (e.g. www.my website.com/index.html)
2. Download every single HTML page from a website recursively excluding external links (basically download the entire website)

I require all the images and links included in all the HTML pages and not just the text only.

I'm currently using scrapy for both functions. It works well, but I want to know if I would be better off using wget or curl.

My question:

Which tool is the best for me to use to achieve my objectives?

Comment: https://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/curl-vs-wget-vs-lynx/ good compression

Answer (score 3):

Wget can do this.

See: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Basically

```
$ wget \
 --recursive \
 --no-clobber \
 --page-requisites \
 --html-extension \
 --convert-links \
 --restrict-file-names=windows \
 --domains website.org \
 --no-parent \
     www.website.org/tutorials/html/
```

`--recursive` should save links

`--page-requisites` should save css, images, etc.

Comment: Is wget better than scrapy?

Comment: i think they do different things.... one is a framework the other is a CLI tool. basically wget will do this all out of the box without writing any additional code other than executing a command with a few flags.

Comment: What you're looking for is making a "local mirror" of a website. wget or any other mirroring tool will do the job. Scrapy is for more complex stuff like extracting structured data from the website or submitting forms.

Answer (score 1):

1.
wget can do this but it can be done easily by using other tools

```
wget -m -k -K -E -p http://url/of/web/site
```

-p is for downloading assets.Wait options -w 10 --random-wait can be added if you are scraping some 3rd party websites.

2.
[HTTRACK](http://www.httrack.com/) is an effective way of copying the contents of an entire site. This tool is able to fetch the pieces necessary to make a website with working code content work offline.

3. [WebCopier](http://www.download.com/WebCopier/3000-2377_4-10028393.html?tag=mncol;pop) on Windows.